# Is it possible to directly invoke Haskell code from Bash and output to stdout?

Tags: bash, haskell, command-line

Is possible to output to stdout a simple Haskell one-liner like

`main = print "Hello World"`

directly from Bash? Something ala `php -r 'echo "Hello World\n";'`

I poked around in the `ghc` options but I didn't see anything that would help me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think I figured it out [from here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/users_guide/modes.html)

```
$ ghc -e "interact (unlines.map reverse.lines)"
hello
olleh
```

UPDATE:

just did some more tests, this works too:

```
echo "hi" | ghc -e "interact (unlines.map reverse.lines)"
// prints "ih"
```

Answer (score 12):

Consider `runhaskell` command which can take piped stdin, for instance like this,

```
echo 'main = print "Hello World"' | runhaskell
```

**Update**

In general you can script Haskell source as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell

main = putStrLn "Hello World"
```

This actually compiles and executes the program, whereas `ghc -e` will evaluate an expression.

Comment: Just tried this out and it seems to run super hella slow compared to `ghc -e`, I wonder why that is? `main = print "Hello" | runhaskell` took `1.371s` when I benchmarked it with `time`, compared to `ghc -e '"Hello"'` took `.207s`

Comment: using ghc -e also loads .ghci config but runhaskell doesn't.

Comment: Gotcha, I think most of the time I'd be looking for `ghc -e`, but it's nice to know that I can do multi-lines if I need to with `runhaskell` (eg `echo 'helloWorld = print "Hello World"; main = helloWorld' | runhaskell`)

Answer (score 10):

You found `ghc -e` yourself. Here are some useful aliases that go well with that:

```
function hmap { ghc -e "interact ($*)";  }
function hmapl { hmap  "unlines.($*).lines" ; }
function hmapw { hmapl "map (unwords.($*).words)" ; }
```

(Discussed in this [old blog post](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/156-Haskell_on_the_Command_Line) of mine.)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote eddie (https://eddie.googlecode.com/) to provide more facilities than "-e". From the linked page:

Eddie adds features to make using it for shell scripting easier:

When given file arguments, eddie feeds them to your function.
Eddie can easily add modules to the namespace you use.
Eddie has options for processing things a line or file at a time.
Eddie will use binary file IO methods when asked to.

Be warned that eddie was my first "real" haskell application, and is seriously in need of a rewrite.